# html2canvas, Chart displays some opacity

Tags: html2canvas, html2pdf, react-chartjs

I am using html2canvas to download the chart, what is the way to download svg ?
On configuring to download PNG/JPEG. It is showing some opacity in downloaded image.

my util code

```
const chartToImage = (format: ChartsType): void => {
   
    let input = window.document.getElementsByClassName("chart_container")[0] as HTMLElement;
  
    let extension: string;
    let mimeType: string;
  
    if (format === ChartsType.JPEG) {
      extension = 'jpg';
      mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
    } else if (format === ChartsType.PNG) {
      extension = 'png';
      mimeType = 'image/png';
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported format: ${format}`);
    }
  
    html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob as Blob);
  
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = blobUrl;
        link.download = `image.${extension}`;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
  
      }, mimeType, 1);
  
    });
  }
```

output

[image]